# The server has rejected the client credentials in Active Directory

Tags: permissions, active-directory

I installed a Windows Server 2012 r2  and Windows 10 client on the virtual machine to learn attacks on active directory structure but when I run the command

`Get-ADComputer -Server SDSH-DC01 -Filter *, I get an error.`

`Get-ADComputer : The server has rejected the client credentials.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADComputer -Server SDSH-DC01 -Filter *
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : SecurityError: (:) [Get-ADComputer], AuthenticationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer`

Comment: Are you running powershell under a user on the domain you created?

Comment: I also installed a domain controller on the server. I defined Windows 10 as a computer for dc